# Mongodb aggregate distinct with unique and sort

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Ranks collection with documents which looks like this:

```
[
    {
       "_id": "1",
       "url": "ex1.com",
       "keyword": "k1",
       "rank": 19,
       "createdAt": "2021-06-02",
       "user": "616c542660d23fc17469b47e"
    },
   {
       "_id": "2",
       "url": "ex1.com",
       "keyword": "k1",
       "rank": 14,
       "createdAt": "2021-06-01",
       "user": "616c542660d23fc17469b47e"
    },
    {
       "_id": "3",
       "url": "ex1.com",
       "keyword": "k2",
       "rank": 8,
       "createdAt": "2021-05-01",
       "user": "616c542660d23fc17469b47e"
    },
    {
       "_id": "4",
       "url": "ex2.com",
       "keyword": "k3",
       "rank": 4,
       "createdAt": "2021-05-01",
       "user": "616c542660d23fc17469b47e"
    }
]
```

users collection with documents which looks like this:

```
[
  {
    _id: "616c542660d23fc17469b47e",
    email: "some@email.com"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to run an aggregation which will return each user object + user's data array that grouped by url, each url object has keywords array that includes unique and last (by date) rank keyword

This is what I tried but the query returns all url's keywords, how can i make it return unique and last (by createdAt date) keywords

```
Rank.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {}
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'users',
                    localField: 'user',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'user'
                }
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    user: {
                        $arrayElemAt: ['$user', 0]
                    },
                    url: '$url',
                    keyword: '$keyword',
                    rank: '$rank',
                    createdAt: '$createdAt',
                }
            },
            {
                $sort: {
                    createdAt: -1
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: '$user._id',
                    user: {
                        $first: '$user'
                    },
                    data: {
                        $push: {
                            id: '$_id',
                            url: '$url',
                            keyword: '$keyword',
                            rank: '$rank',
                            createdAt: '$createdAt',
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ])
```

Expected output:

```
[{
        user: {
            _id: "616c542660d23fc17469b47e",
            email: "some@email.com"
        },
        data: [
            {
                url: "ex1.com",
                keywords: [
                    {
                        keyword: "k1",
                        rank: 19,
                        createdAt: "2021-06-02",
                    },
                    {
                        keyword: "k2",
                        rank: 8,
                        createdAt: "2021-05-01"
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                url: "ex2.com",
                keywords: [
                    {
                        keyword: "k3",
                        rank: 4,
                        createdAt: "2021-05-01"
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }]
```

Comment: post example documents for rank collection.

Comment: Please add sample data for users collection.  Questions with missing or incomplete details are difficult to help with.

Comment: Why does the sample JSON have the value `(ref)`?  Is this a comment for the Stack Overflow audience?  If so, please remove it from the sample documents, and instead add some verbiage describing (ref).

Comment: I came out with this, if this is what you need i will upload a full answer. https://mongoplayground.net/p/vfxpwoKFHQj

Comment: @RubénVega thank you for the answer,
the query returns all url's keywords, how can i make it return unique and last (by createdAt date) keywords. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AlexFadeev I think that what I made is more complex that it should be... but once again this is what I came out with xD. https://mongoplayground.net/p/zk9RUjyNCha

Comment: @RubénVega it works perfect. thank you very very much!! XD XD

Comment: @AlexFadeev Great! Im gald to hear it, I just posted a full answerd detailing bit what each step of the aggregation does. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is the solution that I came out with. [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zk9RUjyNCha)

Full explanation:

We group by "$url","$user" and "$keyword" to get the unique combinations of this fields. AT this point waht we want is only the unique keywords, but we have to use the user and url fields, becouse we would groupBy those later too.Because we order them by createdAt, if we get the first document it will be the last one created.

```
{
    "$sort": {
        "createdAt": 1
    }
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": [
            "$url",
            "$user",
            "$keyword"
        ],
        "keywords": {
      $first: "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
},
```

Then we will format this keyword information a bit to group it by url. This step will give us the keywords per URL.

```
    {
        "$project": {
          "url": "$keywords.url",
          "user": "$keywords.user",
          "keywords": "$keywords",
          "_id": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "$group": {
          "_id": [
            "$user",
            "$url"
          ],
          "data": {
            $push: "$$ROOT"
          }
        }
      },
```

Finally we will group the URLs by user. Notice that we have grouped by URL and by user in each groupBy in order to not lose those fields.

```
  {
    "$project": {
      "url": {
        $first: "$data.keywords.url"
      },
      "user": {
        $first: "$data.keywords.user"
      },
      "keywords": "$data.keywords",
      "_id": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$user",
      "data": {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
```

At this step we have almost all the information we needed grouped together. We would perform a lookUp to get the email from the Users collection and do the final mapping to remove some redundant data.

```
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "user"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$user"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "data.user": 0,
      "data.keywords._id": 0,
      "data.keywords.url": 0,
      "data.keywords.user": 0
    }
  },
```